# (react redux) how to pass params to useSelector and retrieved by createSelector?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently using the `useSelector` hook to pass the `category` params to the redux:

```
const productDataByCategory = useSelector(state => selectProductByCategory(state, category));
```

However, the `createSelector` is not able to retrieve the `category` params, and returned an empty array. the syntax seems okay to me so I don't really know what is the exact problem here:

```
export const {
    selectAll: selectAllProducts,
    selectById: selectProductsById
} = productsAdapter.getSelectors(state => selectProductsData(state) ?? initialState);

export const selectProductByCategory = createSelector(
    selectAllProducts,
    (productsResult, category) => productsResult.filter(item => item.category === category)
);
```

What's is wrong with my code? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createSelector` comes from https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Here is how to pass parameters to your selector:

The second function in the first array will forward the argument, and the final function will receive all elements from the array

```js
const selectProductsByCategory = createSelector(
  [
    selectAllProducts,
    (state, category) => category
  ],
  // Output selector gets (`productsResult, category)` as args
  (productsResult, category) => productsResult.filter(item => item.category === category)
)
```

Here is how to use it with `useSelector`

```js
const productDataByCategory = useSelector(state => selectProductByCategory(state, category));
```

Comment: passing the whole state object will cause the selector to recalculate because inputs of the selector will change on every state update,

I would advise to pass only part of the state